# Mean value theorem sufficient conditions in several variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I was doing a proof which was: If f is defined on an open set A, and all of its partial derivatives EXIST and are BOUNDED at A, then f is continuous.

I used the trick of writng down (just to illustrate in two variables) $f(a+h)-f(a)=f(a_1+h_1,a_2)-f(a_1,a_2)+f(a_1+h_1,a_2+h_2)-f(a_1+h_1,a_2)$ and because the partial derivatives are bounded, it would kill the problem if I could use the mean value theorem for each component.

However, there states in the necessary conditions of the MVT that a function should be differentiable (for single variable case). In this case, beacuse the partial derivatives exist, I think I can assume that the function is "continuous along the directions of each component" and hence use the MVT.

In the end I googled the problem and it turned out my solution was right, the MVT was indeed applied but they didn't state why. And although I had the initial correct idea, in the MVT step I feel like "I have no idea of what I'm doing". Please help.